# Hibernate getting slower after many inserts

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I've got a problem. In my sollution I need to insert thousands datas to database. I am using batch prepare statement to insert many rows in one request. After i call inserting few times, hibernate goes much more slower.

I guess it checks database for changes after my commites. Maybe I need to tel hibernate not to do it, but idk how.

```
Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        while (!stop) {
            if (data.size() == 0) {
                try {
                    t.sleep(100); // další kontrola fronty
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                session.doWork(new Work() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                        try {
                            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO data_data (Data_channelId,Data_nodeAddress,Data_subsystemId,data) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
                            int pocet = data.size();
                            for (int i = 0; i < pocet; i++) {
                                Data item = data.get(0);
                                try {
                                    ps.setByte(1, item.getGlobal_id().getChannelId());
                                    ps.setShort(2, item.getGlobal_id().getNodeAddress());
                                    ps.setInt(3, item.getGlobal_id().getSubsystemId());
                                    ps.setDouble(4, item.getData().get(0));
                                    ps.addBatch();
                                } catch (SQLException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                data.remove(0);
                            }
                            ps.executeBatch();
                            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " Commited: " + pocet);

                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                session.clear();

                try {
                    t.sleep(100); // Zjistit, zda je úspornější nechat větší frontu, nebo ne
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

When I do not use session from hibernate but cerate another one simple Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(... then it works fine.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Many inserts in sequence causes hibernate to slow down gradually. This is because the rows you insert stays in the session until the session is closed or  session is flushed and clear.
I am unable to understand the clearly why did you code in this way, but I would suggest you to call session.flush() and session.clear() inside the for loop after regular intervals. For example if you want to keep batch size as 20 and number of records are 10000, then call flush and clear methods after every 20 records fetched. This will drastically increase the performance.

Comment: If I call session.flush() after the ps.executeBatch(). I get an exception - no transaction is in progress

Comment: Try adding session.flush() before session.clear() in your original code.

Comment: Yes, I did it, but same exception.

Comment: flushing and clearing works, however, the performance is on par with a transaction per job anyway. no speed benefits.